# How to re-scale the x-axis while limiting the value of y-axis with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting in the way like,

```
$ gnuplot -persist -e 'plot "m.dat" u 1:(($2>=4&&$2<=6)?$2:1/0) with line'
$ cat m.dat
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
9 10
```

You can see the y-axis scaled good, but the x-axis doesn't scale. How can I make x-axis scaled too?

[image]

Comment: The x axis did scale.  You have x data values from 1 to 9, the program chose an axis range from 1 to 10.  (Actually I am not sure why it extended from 9 to 10). You may have thought that forcing NaN for some y values would cause the data point to be ignored altogether but that is not the case.  The x value is still used for auto-scaling.   If you want to suppress that x values also, use your filter on the first using spec rather than the second: `plot "m.dat" u (($2>=4&&$2<=6)?$1:1/0):2 with lines`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does work by using your filter on the first using spec rather than the second.

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the range of `x` for which there are `y` values in your range. For this, you need two passes: first store the xmin and xmax, then plot with correct range. This also works with discontinuous ranges:

```
#prepare some data to plot
set table "m.dat"
plot [0:10] x+3*sin(x)
unset table
#calculate x range
xmin=1e10
xmax=-1e10
add_this_x(x)=((x<xmin)?xmin=x:0,(x>xmax)?xmax=x:0,1/0)
plot "m.dat" u 1:(($2>=4&&$2<=6)?add_this_x($1):1/0)
# do the plot
plot [xmin:xmax] "m.dat" u 1:(($2>=4&&$2<=6)?$2:1/0) w lp
```